# Why inline styling doesnt work in react on components?

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles

Why inline styling doesnt work in react on components?I dont understand why this is not working.I know is possible to make it different ways.(with css files for example).Im just corius.The intellisense does not help by inline styling either.Its strange..

```
import "./App.css";
import Button from "./components/Button";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App"  >
      <Button style={{fontSize:"50px"}} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

//this is from Button components

import React from "react";

const Button = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <button>
        Change
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `style` property to the `Button` component:

```
const Button = ({style}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <button style={style}>
        Change
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```